# In Windows, how can I replace `GlobalAlloc` with `new`?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, new-operator, smart-pointers

In Windows, how can I replace `GlobalAlloc` with `new`?

Hello,
I have this snippet of code (from here: ["Reading from a Mailslot"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
that allocate memory with `GlobalAlloc`.

```
DWORD cbRead = 0;
LPTSTR lpszBuffer = (LPTSTR) ::GlobalAlloc(GPTR, cbMessage); //cbMessage is from a call to GetMailslotInfo
if( NULL == lpszBuffer )
    return FALSE;
lpszBuffer[0] = '\0';
BOOL fResult = ::ReadFile(hSlot, lpszBuffer, cbMessage, &cbRead, 0);
if (fResult)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Contents of the mailslot: %s\n"), lpszBuffer);
}
::GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) lpszBuffer);
```

I would like to change the code and use a smart pointer instead of a bare `LPTSTR` (and to get rid of `GlobalFree`) and `new` instead of `GlobalAlloc`.
`cbMessage` is "The size of the next message, in bytes" and so I need something like `malloc` which works for untyped memory, is there any form of `new` suitable to my case?

Comment: This code leaks when `fResult==FALSE`.

Comment: @tibur Yes, I Will fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just call new. Remember to account for sizeof(TCHAR). Also, why do you still have `TCHAR`. It's long past time for that.

Comment: ¤ Using explicit `new` and `delete`, or a smart pointer, in this case, would be dumb. Use a `std::vector<char>`. Also, in general, using Microsoft's `T` macros is pretty dumb unless you want to support use of unchanged MFC in DLLs in Windows 9x. Presumably you're not aiming for that (I don't think current tools support it, you'd need old tools). So, upshot, use a `std::vector` for the above allocation and deallocation. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can't.

The different memory allocation functions (`GlobalAlloc`, `malloc`, `new`, `SysAlloc`, `VirtualAlloc`, `HeapAlloc`) exist because they allocate memory in different ways, different places, different sizes, tag it differently, use different underlying managers, and myriad other differences. Some of them are in the local heap, some global, some virtual, some don't specify, others that allocate memory and do things with it, such as SysAllocString, others that work with COM like CoGetMalloc, and so on.

If a call specifies that one allocator be used, there's likely underlying code that passes the memory to another process or some other behavior requiring that allocator. You can try to use a different one, but it's likely to be undefined behavior.

In order to use smart pointers with the other allocators, there are a few things you can do. The simplest is providing them as the allocator and deallocator functions to the smart pointer class, allowing it to handle things properly. Depending on your pointer of choice, this may require some tweaking, or you may have to put together a basic smart pointer capable of working with that allocator.

For common ones, MFC and/or ATL often have smart pointers and helper functions that work with one or more of the specialized allocators. If using those is possible, you may look into that.

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::scoped_array<TCHAR> buffer(new TCHAR[cbMessage / sizeof(TCHAR)]);
buffer[0] = 0;
BOOL fResult = ::ReadFile(hSlot, buffer.get(), cbMessage, &cbRead, 0);
if (fResult)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Contents of the mailslot: %s\n"), buffer.get());
}
```

This uses a smart pointer to manage the memory, so you don't need to explicitly free it. (A boost [scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm).)

Comment: @alf You can't portably write directly into the memory of std::string. I agree the T stuff is nonsense, but that doesn't seem relevant to the question. And for someone interested in moving to smart pointers, boost is going to be quite useful.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong about std::string. And also sorry, but Boost is not necessary for anything I can imagine here. The standard library has good enough smart pointers.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, good points but I don't think it justifies a -1. There's nothing in the question to indicate that this isn't legacy code still on MBCS. And while there are other choices for the smart pointer, that doesn't render this choice wrong - it was engineered for just this circumstance.

Comment: @alf I disagreed with your comment but I see no reason why it should be deleted.